# on git pull asking to commit the local changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I am doing `git pull,` It says

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
>       Gemfile
>   Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
>   Aborting

I don't remember doing any changes to `gemfile`.

On `git status` nothing is shown apart from all the files that I have removed.

How can I fix it. And How can I remove all the deleted files being shown while I do `git status`.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario you have to use `git stash` refer this link (https://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing)

Comment: This works, but I think this is not the permanent solution for this. Not sure though. 

any idea on second question though?

Answer (score 0):

1. Removal of files is also a change from the previous commit, so commit your changes by using first git add(the files you have edited, not sure about removed) then then git commit. After that, take merge, or,
2. You can also write git checkout `gemfile` before taking merge, if you are sure that you haven't made any changes to it. This will restore `gemfile` to previous commit. Then take the merge.